# Unity 3Dモデルのmesh頂点の移動を取得したい

Tags: unity3d, blender

お世話になっております。
今現在、
 Bldenerで人型3Dモデルにボーンを入れ、重みづけ
 Unityにfbxでインポート
 アニメーションで3Dモデルを動かす
ということをしています。
モデルのmesh頂点に球を表示したいと思い、skinnedmeshrenderのsharedmeshでmeshを取得したのですが、インポートした時の、動く前のmeshしか取得できません。イメージとしては体中に蜂が集まっているような状況を作りたいと考えています。
何かいい方法がありましたらご教授ください。よろしくお願いします。